# Date Paginator Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, date, paginator

I want to use the Date Paginator Bootstrap and take the particular date i click.

I triede to use it as belows, but from this im getting the alert even if click on a arrow.

```
<!--BEGIN LOADING CSS FOR PAGE-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepaginator/bootstrap-datepaginator.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepaginator/datepicker.css">
<!--END LOADING CSS FOR PAGE-->

<!--BEGIN HTML-->
<div class="paginator paginator-select paginator-success"></div>
<!--END HTML-->

<!--BEGIN LOADING SCRIPTS FOR PAGE-->
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepaginator/moment.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepaginator/bootstrap-datepaginator.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap-datepaginator/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<!--END LOADING SCRIPTS FOR PAGE-->

<!--BEGIN JAVASCRIPT-->
<script>
    $('.paginator-select').datepaginator({
        onSelectedDateChanged: function (event, date) {
            alert("Selected date: " + moment(date).format("Do, MMM YYYY"));
        }
    });
</script>
<!--END JAVASCRIPT-->
```

What can i do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Git repository for bootstrap-datepaginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator) there is no such method to retrieve date but you can write value in some global variable in the event you have handled and use it later, I did same :)
 Only one care you need to take that on pageload initialize your variable with initial date of paginator.